# Proper design of REST-powered list in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the following:

- There's a view that displays the list of items
- I take the list of items from the backend via RESTful interface in JSON using ember-data and hand-crafted adapter
- In my view I do something like this:

  ```
  {{#collection contentBinding="App.recentAdditionsController"}}
    ...
  {{/collection}}
  ```
- `App.recentAdditionsController` is defined like this:

  ```
  App.recentAdditionsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    refresh: function(query) {
      var items = App.store.findAll(App.Item);
      this.set('content', items);
    }
  });
  ```

And... this doesn't work. The reason being `App.store.findAll()` returning `ModelArray` which is much like `ArrayController` itself.

I saw people doing something like this:

```
App.recentAdditions = App.store.findAll(App.Item);
```

I could imagine doing it like that, but how would I refresh the list at will (checking if there's anything new).

Hope all is clear more or less.

Comment: I'd suggest while learning Ember, just use `jQuery.ajax()` inside a controller to load your JSON data. There are many people using it quite successfully in apps without ember-data.

Comment: what exactly is failing? can you create a JSFiddle with what you're seeing?

Comment: It's not exactly failing. I'm just not sure how to design it so that every time I need to refresh the list of items, I didn't need to set the 'content' of the controller, but rather update the underlying array with new records and let the controller pick those updates. I know how to add objects manually `this.get('content').pushObject(...)`, but given that `content` is a proxy object I got from calling `store.findAll`, it feels like there has to be a way to let it update itself somehow (querying the backend and merging the results). Just looking for design guideline, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I've verified that you can use a `ModelArray` inside an `ArrayController`. Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ebryn/VkKX2/

Comment: Thanks. That's where I got myself. Now the question is how to make the list update itself if there are new objects in the backend? Imagine having this comments thread loaded from backend into `CommentsController.content` with `App.store.findAll(App.Comments)`. Now I want to refresh the list every 5 seconds, but don't want to do setting `content` property over and over with new array. I'd prefer fetching the updates only and merging them with what I already have. Is that a bit more clear? Sorry for being vague.

Answer (score 0):

"Now the question is how to make the list update itself if there are new objects in the backend?"

Use App.Model.filter to keep your recordArray in sync. Add the query hash when the filter is invoked to ensure than an initial query was made.

```
model: ->
  App.Model.filter {page: 1}, (data) ->
    data
```

edit: Just saw how old the question was, but leaving it here in case it helps someone.